# Creating a local library with network shares/drives

Tags: windows-7, file-management, network-shares

I think the Windows 7 library feature is great - once you understand how it works, but it's pretty frustrating that you can't add network drives/shares to a library.

I fully understand that in some circumstances users might find it confusing to have something available one minute and not the next - i.e. when they go offline. I also understand when MS say that to add a network drive/share you need to mark that particular folder as "Always available offline"... All good. For laptop users with documents on a file share that is.

However, for desktop users wanting to have libraries of network folders having them marked as 'available offline' seems a pretty harsh penalty on local disk usage and in some cases would simply not work because of network folder size/local disk size.

With the exception of 'tricking' windows into thinking a remote folder is local (i.e. with a symbolic link, or a subst'd drive, or even a mapped drive) .... is there an alternative? I've read somewhere on the Interwebs that MS have a patch out there but haven't been able to find it.

Thanks.

Comment: A really good question and I would be very interested in a solution too. +1

Comment: I've read the 'tricks' but have not even successfully done that. Link to a working 'hack'?

Comment: The "Always available offline" feature is apparently only available in Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate editions of Windows 7, so it isn't a universal solution either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add network shares to a Windows 7 library, however, they have to be indexed on the server that is sharing them, install [Windows Search 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/choose/windowssearch4.mspx?tab=Install%20It) on the server and make sure you index the folders you intend to add to your Windows 7 library.

Comment: Anyone knows how to index a Unix (Samba) share?

Comment: After you install Windows Search on the server side, make sure the Shares's *Share permissions* gives Read access to *Everyone* group

Answer (score 3):

This was the very first thing I tried to do when I discovered libraries in Windows 7. Luckily Microsoft have provided a programatic way to add network locations, so I wrote a tool to make this easy. It also provides some additional features like backup/restore of library sets. You can download it for free (+ WPF source) here:

[Win7 Library Tool](http://zornsoftware.codenature.info/blog/win7-library-tool.html)

Comment: Nice tool indeed, however it doesn't make Windows Index the network share

Answer (score 1):

You can add network drives if they are part of your homegroup.  I think the drive just has to be indexed by a copy of windows 7 before it can be used in a library.
The windows help and support covers what you can and can't add pretty completely.  I searched for "library" and when to **Libraries: frequently asked questions**.

Answer (score 0):

I found this discussion while creating a solution to add indexed network drives to your library.

Maybe the write up helps other users having the same issue:
http://www.cloudtec.ch/blog/tech/add-search-indexed-network-share-windows-library.html

Regards

PS: It requires a Windows Server...

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.