# How can I use shortcuts in this minimalist Windows folder browser dialog?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, adobe-illustrator

This is the folder chooser window that pops up on Adobe Illustrator CS6 running on Windows (8.1 pro) when a script calls for a file or folder to be selected (on the left below - this example is from the [multiexporter script](https://gist.github.com/TomByrne/7816376) but it's not specific to that script):

[image]

My biggest issue with it is that **folder shortcuts are not shown at all** in this view, not even when navigating to folders they are in. This plus the fact there is no option of typing a location makes folders in nested network drives based on domains and URLs, which I normally navigate to using shortcuts, seemingly impossible to reach using this dialog (the domains don't appear under `Network`).

It's very different to other file or folder selection views used for saving, opening etc. I know that Adobe have been much-criticised for using old and obsolete Windows file selection windows elsewhere in their UI ([for example keeping Windows 95 style save and open dialogs](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/please_update_outmoded_open_save_menus_in_adobe_products)). Some guesswork combined with google image search turned up [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script) which suggests it's called the **"Folder Browser Dialog"**, apparently invoked by `new FolderBrowserDialog`.

So, how can I get a shortcut - or something equivalent - to be visible and usable in it? Suppose I have regular working directories which have complex paths based on a domain. How can I enable myself to quickly and efficiently reach it using this dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this in Windows 8.1 is to create a custom Library.

[image: File dialog with a custom Library]

Note that you might not be able to include a network folder within a Library if it is not indexed. See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/41991/234790) for solutions to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your own comments to the related SO post, the developers, namely Adobe are using a folder picker. It does just as it states on the tin and allows users to select a folder. So by design, it ignores all files and shortcuts alike and only displays folders to the user. You won't be able to get them to show in that dialog.

Can you make them visible? The short answer is, by design, no.

Comment: My problem is that the folder I want to pick is nested deep down a complex domain-based path that is inaccessible in this window - I'm not trying to pick a shortcut, I'm trying to navigate to a folder, *using* a shortcut for what shortcuts are designed for (quick navigation)

Comment: I appreciate what your problem is but you're effectively trying to square a circle in the respect that the window won't do as you want unfortunately and as you quite rightly stated in your OP, Adobe have been criticised for the Window UI's they have adopted.